# Why does importing symbols from a module also define the module symbol?

Tags: python

Given a trivial Python package with an `__init__.py`:

```
$ ls -R foo/
foo/:
__init__.py  bar.py

$ cat foo/bar.py
def do_stuff(): pass

$ cat foo/__init__.py
from .bar import *
```

I'm surprised that `foo.bar` is defined:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.bar
<module 'foo.bar' from 'foo/bar.pyc'>
```

My understanding of `from x import *` is that it doesn't define `x` in the current scope. For example:

```
>>> from abc import *
>>> abc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'abc' is not defined
```

Why is `foo.bar` defined in my first example, even though I don't have `import bar` inside `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 1):

When you reference it by `foo.bar`, it is not referencing to `bar` used in the import statement in `__init__.py` file, instead it is a reference to `bar` module/file itself. Even if you remove all the code in `__init__.py` file, `import foo; foo.bar` would still work.

If that weren't the case, you wouldn't have been able to do something like this

```
import foo.bar
```

Since `foo` is a package, as it contains `__init__` file, hence it's internal files can be referenced directly.